# Capturing groups in istio

Tags: istio, envoyproxy

How can I use a part of matched URI in destination rule in istio?

Trying to achieve something like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
spec:
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        regex: "^/foo/(.+)/?$"
    route:
    - destination:
        host: bar-$1
        port:
          number: 80
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know this is not possible at all.
Cant provide you any  confirmation link on this.
The similar question was here in the past:
[can istio support route to different service by dynamic part of uri path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54503758/can-istio-support-route-to-different-service-by-dynamic-part-of-uri-path)